# Double pulse test drain current not reaching peak

Tags: mosfet, simulation, switching, gate-driving, pspice

I want to have a double pulse test for the [MOSFET](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/sic/mosfet/sct3160kl-e.pdf). The drain current needs to reach 17 A peak. So to choose the capacitor and inductor I did the following,

DC Bus voltage = 400 V

$$L\dfrac{di}{dt} = V_{DCBus}$$

Taking $$L = 400 \mu H, di = 17, V_{DCBus} = 400V$$
the time is 17 microseconds.
And taking $$C\Delta V_{DC} = 0.5I_{pk}(\Delta t)$$
I get C = 36 uF. (Taking voltage ripple as 1% of DC Bus voltage).

But the simulation the drain current does not reach 17 A, and the dt time does not match either. What am I doing wrong here? My main aim is to get 17 A drain current of the lower MOSFET.

This is the drain current.
[image]

[image]
The blue is the VGS of lower MOSFET.

[image]

EDIT:-
I tried using 340V, L = 100 uH, C = 12.5 uF which should give 17A peak current for the MOSFET being turned on for 5 microseconds, but I got this, (blue is the drain current).

[image]

Comment: You are only turning on the FET for 5us. 400uH with 400V gives 1A/us so you should have a peak current of 5A, which you do. It looks like the simulation is working properly.

Comment: @KevinWhite Thanks for pointing that out. But when I changed the pulse width to 17us, keeping the pulse width the same it still didn't work, so I'm confused how to setup the "double pulses", or if it's a mistake of the L and C

Comment: @KevinWhite please see the edit and it'll be great if you could help me out!

Comment: What happens if you remove V40 and set V39 to PW=17us?

Comment: What is the red trace? U16 VDS?

Comment: @KevinWhite yes the red trace is the VDS of U16.

Comment: @KevinWhite I found the problem. The OC pin was sensing an overcurrent, and that's why the \FLT pin went low, and turned the whole thing off. That's why I didn't get a second pulse either when I tried to make it go high. Fixed it!